Is it safe to update an iPad running iPadOS 17.4 to iPadOS 17.7.1 or 18.1 if there is no passcode and no affiliated AppleID?
I have an iPad running iPadOS 17.4. It is not affiliated with an AppleID and does not have a passcode set. Online, I found reports that updating a device in this state sometimes leads to a lockout and a de-facto bricked and/or wiped device.
Question: Could this happen if I allow the above described machine to update to either iPadOS 17.7.1 or 18.1?
The key issues seem to be

An iPadOS update altering settings to activate a passkey lock where none was previously used.
The device being in an inconsistent or unexpected state causing an unknown value to be used for the passkey.
A lack of device affiliation with a known Apple ID preventing device recovery without data loss, per Apple's policies.


Evidence of nonzero risk
Evidence of risk of lockout for iPads with no passcode set

iPadOS 10 update
iPadOS 14.1 update
Further evidence that this happened with the iPadOS 14.1 update
A long thread with multiple user reports of lockouts from iPads expressly set up without passcodes, which includes multiple skeptical or invalidated responses, as well as user counters to said responses.
An invalidating forum response suggesting that a passcode must exist if face/touch ID were ever used --- but these have both been expressly not used on this device.
A thread specifically evidencing that iPads will lock users out after updates even if passcode is disabled.
Another misunderstood and/or dismissive response to a user with a similar issue
Another thread indicating iPadOS updates generally don't respect disabled passcodes.
User reports passcode requested despite none being set (1)(2)(3)
Evidence that, even with a passcode set, incompatibility across versions could lock-out users. Similarly disappointing news for a related user experience issue on iPhone can be found here.
Here is a forum response suggesting that a passcode being set and entered is a foregone conclusion in the update process. However, the device has downloaded updates waiting to install without this. This supports the concern that the device may be in an unusual part of the update flow/path and at risk for glitches should one click continue.
This thread is a bit ambiguous, as it is ultimately blamed on people with dementia accidentally setting a code after updates for devices configured without one. However, this very earnest comment in said thread does indicate that requiring nonexistent passcodes after updates does sometimes happen.

Evidence of risk for devices not linked to an Apple ID
This forum post will evidence that Apple does not support possession of a device as indicating ownership, should the update process lead to a lockout/glitch:

Unless you are the owner of the AppleID that was last used to activate the device, or unless you can secure the cooperation of the previous owner, you’ll not be able to defeat or bypass the Activation Lock. Without documentary evidence that you are the original owner (such as sales receipt showing the serial number), Apple won’t assist - and nobody here will be able to help you.

I have not consented to an ongoing relationship with Apple Inc., So have never bound the device to an Apple ID. Thus, this is evidence that there may be no recovery path should the update lead to a locked device. Here are further corroborating links, (1)(2),  although this appears to be a well-known

Do you have references for that claim? Can you add links and/or quotes to your question?

Hi Martin, I made this post because I couldn't find any specific reference for this OS version. I can find forum posts alleging difficulties with previous updates, but I don't think they'd meet your standards of evidence. The only way for me to gather said evidence would be to attempt the updates and assume the risk should something go awry, which is a bad idea. I was imagining that the software ecosystem was well-understood enough that someone could verify that the process is safe, rather than taking this risk.

Hi Martin, I hope the now-added research works for your needs.

Practically speaking, there isn’t a lot of hard evidence for a missing passcode being a problem when updating to 18.1. OTOH it seems to happen, so why risk it? Just set a passcode temporarily, run the upgrade, and remove it again afterwards.
